# O(1) Exponential summation

Tags: summation

Is there an O(1) (uses a function instead of summation/for loop notation) way to calculate
$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^n x^i
$$
`Given (x,n)
Example:
(4,3)
64+16+4+1
(3,3)
27+9+3+1
(2,10)
1024+...+8+4+2+1
I know that for x=2, f(x,n)=(x^(n+1))-1`
I am in search of a general solution for all x,n.

Comment: $$f(x,n) = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1},$$ unless $x = 1$, in which case $f(1,n) = n+1$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: Thanks, it just dawned upon me that this was a geometric series. I had been searching for terms that seemed to fit this, but terminology kills me.
I came across this in the process, which has other relevant information.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). The general formula is given by
$$f(x,n) = \sum_{i=0}^n x^i = \begin{cases}\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1} & x\neq 1\\ n+1 & x=1\end{cases}$$
Assuming $0^0 = 1$